# Resizable bubble chart

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am using the D3js bubble chart example (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) and cant make the chart resize to fit the current page. How would I do this?

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300"></svg>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Harrison and Gerardo,

I have created a block which uses bootstrap to demonstrate the viewbox capability for the same chart.

link to the block is :- https://bl.ocks.org/tejaser/c69f2f20cec53dd166dcb26ca43c2ae9/d57b7c6898fae90d586df16459730cc2226b4740

I have used 8-4 and 6-6 column split in two different rows to show how the SVG modifies itself to maintain the aspect ratio based on the container.  I have used "xMinYMin meet" in the example, replacing it with "xMidYMid meet" does not have affect on the final output.

Answer (score -1):

You want this SVG to scale and retain aspect ratio filling its container? Be sure that SVG is set to "display: block" and try using:
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet"